# 1-Con(T), modification

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

$1-$Con($T$) says

$$Pr_T([\exists \phi x])\to\exists x \neg Pr_T([\neg\phi \dot{x}]).$$

My concern is what says this:

$$Pr_T([\exists \phi x])\to\exists x Pr_T([\phi \dot{x}]).$$

Is it weaker or equivalent or not interesting at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property in question **never** holds (assuming $T$ is "reasonable"), and its strongest actually-possible variation is just $1$-consistency itself.

Towards the first point, consider what happens if we look at $\phi(x) \equiv$ "Either $T$ is consistent, or $x$ is a (code for a) $T$-proof of $\perp$." Trivially we have $Pr_T(\exists x\phi(x))$, but we must also have $\neg\exists xPr_T(\phi(x))$ by the second incompleteness theorem.

Towards the second point, note that this $\phi$ is $\Pi_1$. The version of your proposed property with $\phi$ restricted to $\Sigma_1$ formulas is in fact just $1$-consistency, since any "reasonable" $T$ is $\Sigma_1$-complete.

Comment: I do not follow this: Trivially we have $Pr_T(\exists x\phi(x))$

Comment: @user122424 $T$ trivially proves "Either $T$ is consistent or $T$ is inconsistent." Now reason (in $T$) by cases: if $T$ is consistent then every $x$ satisfies $\phi$, and if $T$ is inconsistent then some $x$ satisfies $\phi$ by coding a contradiction.